# Difference action for different files

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I want to monitor new files created in a folder.
When this happens I want to launch a batch file (in the example below I just write a line in a log file).
I don't know why this doesn't work.

My code is:

```cs
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "D:\"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"

    if ($file.Name -like "Apertura") {
        Add-Content "C:\Users\F701845\Desktop\Apertura.txt" -Value $logline
    } else {
        Add-Content "C:\Users\F701845\Desktop\TestNO.txt" -Value $logline
    }
}

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: Please describe how it's failing - there's no obvious reason in the code for the failure, so any associated error messages would be helpful.

Comment: My guess is that `$file.Name -like "Apertura"` should be `$file.Name -like "*Apertura*"` As `-like` without `*` as a wildcard is the same as `-eq`

Answer (score 1):

Well this one is easy, you are using a variable that is empty in your IF/ELSE.
$path and $changeType are derived from $Event but $file is not existing at all.

First take a look at what you have and you will see that you might be able to use in this case: $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name.

```
$Event.SourceEventArgs | Get-Member

bool Equals(System.Object obj)
int GetHashCode()
type GetType()
string ToString()
System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes ChangeType {get;}
string FullPath {get;}
string Name {get;}
```

While it does work, it still looks for files called exactly Apertura meaning Apertura.txt  wont work, i would recommend using something like Apertura.* if you do not know the extension.

Example Code:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\test\"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {

    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $file = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name #get filename from Event data  
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"

    if ($file -like "Apertura.*") { #removed the .Name and added .*
        Add-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Apertura.txt" -Value $logline
    } else {
        Add-Content "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestNO.txt" -Value $logline
    }
}

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}

$watcher.Dispose() #can be used to dispose the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
```